# Decltype for return of a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

I am making a templated class that is a wrapper around any iterator. I am making the operator* this way:

```
template <typename T>
class MyIterator {
public:
    //...
    decltype(*T()) operator*() {
    //...
    }
}
```

I give decltype a invocation to operator* of class T, and it even works, but if T doesnt have default constructor it wont work.

Is there anyway to find out the returned type of a function/method ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what `std::declval` is for:

```
decltype(*std::declval<T>()) operator*() { /* ... */ }
```

If your implementation does not provide `std::declval` (Visual C++ 2010 does not include it), you can easily write it yourself:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval(); // no definition required
```

---

Since `T` is an iterator type, you could also use the `std::iterator_traits` template, which does not require any C++0x support:

```
typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference operator*() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: My compiler says "declval() must not be used!"

Comment: What, exactly, does your compiler say (and what compiler are you using?)  You cannot _ODR-use_ `declval` because it is not defined; you can only "use" it in contexts where it will not be evaluated, e.g. in a `decltype`.

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/type_traits:1134:7: error: static assertion failed: "declval() must not be used!"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LrACx9UB , it is included by a test case using boost unittest framework.

Comment: Your code compiles just fine with gcc 4.7. No static asserts failed.

Comment: Compiles fine in GCC 4.6.1, too (remember `-std=c++0x`).