# Free function with parameters, get return type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function on which i'd like to have the variable that returns the computed value be automatically deduced from the return type of the function.

I have seen [Decltype for return of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837444/decltype-for-return-of-a-function?rq=1) for member functions and i know that with `decltype(func()) var` i can get the return type. But that only works for functions without a parameter. If I have a parameter i have to `decltype(func(/* some dummy value convertible to argument type*/))` to get the return type.

is there any way of doing the above without needing to specify a dummy value?

```
auto func(int a) -> std::deque<decltype(a)> {

  // lots of code

  /* ideally */
  decltype(func)::return_type result;

  /* fill result*/

  return result;
}
```

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18695564/1782465) useful.

Comment: Maybe you'll find useful the paper n3638: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html knowed as **Return type deduction for normal functions**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the argument types, since different overloads can have different return types.

You can specify a dummy argument using `declval`:

```
#include <utility>

decltype(func(std::declval<ArgType>())) result;
```

or you can avoid giving a dummy value by using type traits:

```
#include <type_traits>

std::result_of<decltype(func), ArgType>::type result;
```

Comment: Any way of getting the ArgType for the function where result is defined in?

Comment: @RedX: No. Since functions can be overloaded, you can't specify which function you mean without specifying the whole signature, including the argument types.

Comment: You are right, but in my case i could with `decltype(func(std::declval<decltype(arg_name)>()))`.

Comment: @RedX: Yes, that's right; I misunderstood the question, and thought you wanted to get the argument type from the function.

Comment: @RedX In this case, you can skip the `declval<decltype()>` thing (which is just inverse of each other), and do `decltype(func(arg_name))` directly.